# Simple array.map causing hydration error in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a strange hydration error in NextJS!  I wonder if anyone can help me get to the bottom of it?

I have an object which gets processed synchronously. If i stringify this object and render it, i dont get an error.

but if, after stringifying it, i map through it, I get this hydration error.

What could be going on here?

```js
const OpponentList = ({ opponents }: Props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(opponents)}</p>  // NO ERROR


      {opponents.map((opponent) => {.    // HYDRATION ERROR
        return <li key={opponent.username}>{opponent.username}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};


export default OpponentList;
```

Comment: This is happening because the server side rendered content is differ than the client side rendered content. What you could do is check if the page is mounted by using useEffect, and show the mapped content. Hope you got it.

Comment: How to do that?

But oddly if i stringify the props, that doesnt cause a hydration error, which means that the content is the same at teh render time? is it only the map that's happening at render time?

Comment: It only looks for HTML elements. For answer to your question is although you are stringifying it, it is inside the same <p> tag. So there is no difference in the HTML elements.

Comment: Can you remove `p` and check? I think this causing the issue

Comment: Yes without the P, it does have a hydration error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Next.js, you can get rid of these issues by doing the asynchronous calls inside getServerSideProps method. If you do it like that, expecting data would be available in the client side when the client visits the page (No need to do the API calls from the client side).

Anyway if you really want to do it in client side, you could use something like this.

```
const OpponentList = ({ opponents }: Props) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
   }, [])

  return mounted ? (
    <ul>
  
      {opponents.map((opponent) => {.    // HYDRATION ERROR
        return <li key={opponent.username}>{opponent.username}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  ): <div/>;
};


export default OpponentList;
```

Comment: Thank you, odd... actually i dont have any asynchronous calls - I'm fetching the data way up the tree in a GetServersideProps, and then synchronously parsing it.

Comment: Then it would be fine. Is there any possibility that you can post the code of the parent component where this OpponentList is being used.

Comment: Thanks @Dulaj -  It's getting fetched here: https://github.com/fotoflo/chesskid-charts/blob/1333e520b9b5d7dd92b58acf170233eda6ec68c7/pages/rating.tsx#L41

and getting passed down from the parent here: https://github.com/fotoflo/chesskid-charts/blob/1333e520b9b5d7dd92b58acf170233eda6ec68c7/components/rating/RatingContainer.tsx#L79
You can see the data getting processed synchronously here:
https://github.com/fotoflo/chesskid-charts/blob/1333e520b9b5d7dd92b58acf170233eda6ec68c7/components/rating/RatingContainer.tsx#L41

Comment: I resolved the error: 

```
  const initialEndDate = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  const now = new Date();
  const initialStartDate = new Date(now.getDate() - 30).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  const initialData = processRatingData(
    fullData,
    initialStartDate,
    initialEndDate
  );
```

If if takes time to process the initial data, then the initial start time must be synchronized.

Comment: Okay glad to hear it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Stringfied form will not get parse through map. .map() is not the property of a string. It needs to be an array. So Either perform `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(opponents))` or use `opponents.map` directly (if opponents is an array).

Comment: Thank you for your response

I am using opponents.map directly, and that's where the hydration error is getting thrown

I showed the JSON.stringify to show that there is no hydration error there.